# How to mix in additional validations to ActiveModel::Model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, metaprogramming, mixins

I have a form class that includes ActiveModel::Model module in order to have basic validations

```
class RegistrationForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  ...
  validates_presence_of ....
end
```

I'd like to add some additional class validation methods like below

```
class RegistrationForm
  include ActiveModel::Model
  ...
  my_custom_class_validation_method
end
```

And I want this method to be automatically included when ActiveModel::Model module is included.

I tried to use solution like here: [adding class methods to ActiveRecord::Base](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2921215/adding-class-methods-to-activerecordbase)
but with no luck.

Is this possible at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay.
One more snippet. 
Im not sure, but how about this?

```
# This should be locate in lib/your_custom_validator.rb
class YourCustomValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    # validation login is here
  end
end

I think, now you can use that validator in any model. 


# You can use that validator like this. 
class RegistrationForm < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :some_column_name, your_custom_validator: true
end
```

cheers, Sangil.

Comment: Thanks @humbroll. This approach works without any problems and solves my issue in context of validation. However I'm still curious whether is this possible to add another class method (diffrerent than validation one) to my form class when I include ActiveModel::Model. This is Ruby, there must be a way to accopmlish this ...

Answer (score 0):

This code snippet could be good start.

```
module ActiveModel
  module Model
    def self.included(base)
      base.extend(ClassMethods)
      base.class_eval %{
            class << self
              def your_custom_validator
              end
            end  
          }
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: After some adjustments I forced this snippet to start working - however this is not the way I want. I had to copy content of self.included function from Rails source and then add the piece with class_eval. From unknown reasons just calling super() does not work.  Full working code is here:  https://gist.github.com/chrosciu/6834015 This solution is strongly dependent of internal implementation of ActiveModel::Model and can become brittle ... :( However thanks for answer.

Comment: What you're asking for is that `ActiveModel::Model` brings in your custom code, so this suggestion seems inline with that.  Without actually monkey-patching `ActiveModel::Model` how is it going to know to include your custom validator.  I agree that it is a little brittle which is why your other approach with `ExtendedModel` makes good sense.  In that way you're explicitly making a new custom version of `ActiveModel::Model` which is just for your application.  Definitely less fragile.  This was an interesting thoughtful thread/question.

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach - I build new module that includes ActiveModel::Model in itself and is extended with new validation method.

```
module ExtendedModel
  module ClassMethods
    def my_custom_validation_method(*args)
      # define validation here
    end
  end

  def self.included(base)
    base.class_eval do
      include ActiveModel::Model
      extend ClassMethods
    end
  end
end
```

Then I included this new module in my form class

```
class RegistrationForm
  include ExtendedModel

  my_custom_validation_method
  ...
end
```

Of course this solution is not 100% elegant:

1. it requires that all my extensions must be added to ExtendedModel
   module.
2. models that inherit from ActiveRecord::Base must be
       supplied with these extra methods separately

Comment: Cool mix in solution. I agree with that is not perfect solution, but i think that is most elegant stuff in ruby. but, i wonder when did you need like this code? usually i dont need global scope function in ruby. just for specific few classes or modules are enough.